# How large is Daeho?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

The series *Alchemy of Souls* is set in a country called Daeho, which is presumably fictional, since it is described as not appearing on maps or being recorded in history. Although the majority of the plot takes place in the capital city, several other villages and forts (cities, seemingly) are mentioned. That naturally raises the question of Daeho's geography: Joseon, from which it seems to take some inspiration, was something like 300 or 400 miles in its longest dimension. However, there is evidence that points to Daeho being both much smaller (horses seem to play a small role in transport, characters seem to be able to get from one place to another in a matter of days) and perhaps even larger (the Gwanju, probably the second or third most famous person in the country, can go wandering for years or decades without anyone or their spies having any idea where he went).

As such, how large is the country of Daeho?

Comment: A very brief look at the episode synopses would suggest that it's precisely as large as the plot requires at any given moment

Comment: @Valorum - Which parts of the episode synopses lend themselves to that idea?

Comment: Netflix talks about it being in "a magical kingdom" and describes various characters as being essentially aristocrats with their own fiefdoms, but also somehow close enough that they're able to drop in on each other as the plot requires, instead of this being a major feat of traveling.

Comment: @Valorum - Think of them more as noble houses or clans in a capital city, as in the case of Joseon or indeed some famous European examples ("fair Verona, where we lay our scene"). Each of them has a modestly extensive compound in the capital where the family and servants live and a great deal of influence in the court, but they do not have fiefdoms. Some further-flung cities seem to have noble houses that oversee them in the name of the monarch, but they are not their own fiefs in the usual sense.

Comment: I'd be interested to see if any of the show's makers have given it any more thought than just "as big as we need it to be"

Comment: @Valorum - So am I. Another note is that only one or two characters are actually from (more minor) noble houses outside the capital city, and they are staying at one of the mage compounds during their stay to train (they do not go back and forth). In general, the families seem to be heavily associated with a school of mages, but they also take in non-family members on occasion.